# Awkard TFS upgrade

Tags: tfs

I have TFS 2013 application running on Windows Server 2012R2 connected to a SQL Server 2012 instance which is using windows failover clustering.

A new set of servers with failover clustering have been set up using SQL2017, now I must move the TFS app to windows server 2016, upgrade the TFS application to TFS2018 and move the databases to the new SQL servers.

I'm a little confused about the steps and looking for some guidance, the plan I have is below:

1. Remove the database from the failover cluster and set them up up on their own standalone server of sql2012 and remap the app to point at these databases.
2. Upgrade TFS application to TFS2015 update 3.
3. Upgrade SQL Server to SQL Server 2016
4. Upgrade TFS app to TFS 2018.
5. Set up new TFS app on a windows 2016 server and map to databases.
6. Move databases to the SQL Server 2017 failover cluster.

It's a very longwinded process so looking does anyone know of another way to do this or is this my only option?

Comment: Did you review Microsoft's upgrade documentation?

Comment: Yes and this was the conclusion I came to after reading it since I cant go straight to 2018 with the sql versions not being supported

Answer (score 0):

It's supported to upgrade TFS 2013 to TFS 2018 directly.

[image]

As TFS 2018 only supports **SQL Server 2017** and **SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)**, upgrade SQL Server is necessary.

You need to go through article [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4grh.png) before doing upgrade. And follow the steps in article [Upgrade scenario walkthrough for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough) to upgrade your TFS. Summarize the steps here:

> 1. Prepare your environment. The first step is to check the [system
>    requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for TFS 2018. Upgrade SQL Server is necessary for your
>    scenario. Including SQL Server, you also need to check other system
>    requirements and prepare the environment.
> 2. Expect the best, prepare for the worst. You must have a complete and
>    consistent set of [database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) in case something goes wrong.
> 3. Do the upgrade. Once the preparation is done, you'll need to install
>    the new version of TFS to get new binaries, and then run through the
>    upgrade wizard to upgrade your databases.
> 4. Configure new features. Depending on what version you upgraded from,
>    you may need to [configure each team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access to some
>    of the new features made available.

Here is a useful blog for your reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/